# How to free an array of structures inside a structure?

Tags: c, structure

I have the following code.:

```
struct O1 {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct O2 {
    int f;
    int g;
    struct O1 *array;      //pointer to an array of structs O1
};

struct O2 *list = malloc(25 * sizeof(struct O1));        //array of 25 structs O2

struct O1 *innerlist = malloc(sizeof(struct O1));    //array of structs O1 contained inside each struct O2

innerlist[0].a = 1;
innerlist[0].b = 2;
innerlist[0].c = 3;

(*list)[0].f = 1;
(*list)[0].g = 1;
(*list)[0].array = &innerlist[0];    //filling the parameters via some loop for example
```

So my question is, did I allocate the arrays correctly?

For the inner structure contained inside each `struct O2`, I only wanted an array with just one element (one `struct O1`) that I could then expand further via `realloc` for example but I tried storing more `struct O1`s in `struct O2` and it works so there must have been more memory allocated somewhere even though I did not multiply the `sizeof` by anything when creating the array of `struct O1`.

I also have a question, how do I free the arrays?

I guess I must first free the inner array first but I am having trouble here.

I have created a function for freeing the memory that takes the array of `struct O2` as a parameter.

But when I type `free(list->obj)`; it seems to be freeing the obj of the first `struct O2` in the list and `free(list[n]->obj)` does not seem to be working.

Comment: Numeric identifiers like `struct 01` will not compile. Did you intend capital-O `struct O1`? There are some missing `;` too after the `struct` definitions. Is this your code?

Comment: This code does not compile.  Please show us some compilable code that exhibits the issue.

Comment: Also `(*list)[0]` is syntactically equivalent to `*((*list)+0)`. This is wrong I think. You said your example compiles. Can you post that example please?

Comment: It's difficult to answer when you provide that has too many compiler errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Create an array of O2:

```
struct O2 *list = malloc(25 * sizeof(struct O2));
```

2 Allocate space for 1 O1 in each O2

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    list[i].array = malloc(sizeof(struct O1));
}
```

3 Free the mem

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    free(list[i].array);
}
free(list);
```

Comment: This looks good. Will that allocate an array of structs 01 though but with just one element? I mean, can I expand it later and add more structs 01 to the array?

Comment: Yes. In the original post you said you wanted just one element. You can allocate more  - `malloc(sizeof(struct O1) * 100);` - or `realloc` later.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. How about filling the elements of struct 01 though? Lets say inside a function where the argument is the array of structs 02. I have tried (*list)[i].obj->id = 1; for example but this does not work.

Comment: You would treat it like a regular array: `list[x].array[y].a = 1;`

Comment: Something is wrong with my allocation as the program crashes. My function takes a parameter struct 02 **ptr which is a pointer to a pointer to the array. I then allocate the main array like this *ptr = malloc(25 * sizeof(struct O2)); Then run the for loop like this for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    ptr[i]->array = malloc(sizeof(struct O1)); And try to fill the parameters of the structures like this:  (*ptr)[n].f = 1; (*ptr)[n].array[0].a = 1;

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems to be working! One last question, if I later add more structs to the inner array, do I need to free them one by one? Or do I just type free(p[i].array and the whole array will be freed?

Comment: The second thing. If you use `realloc` you can then use one single call to `free`.

Comment: Strange thing is, I have a function for adding more structs to the inner array and i just tried it without allocating any more memory and it added fine. So somewhere, there is more memory than there should be I think. Not that its a big issue, just wondering what could be the cause.

Comment: False alarm, it seems to be working properly now, thanks a lot for all your help! : )